# design app for tablets eclipse google play

Tags: android, eclipse

I have designed an app but google play says: Your app isn't designed for tablets.
How can i fix this?

I've tryed to find answers on stackoverflow and google but can't find any solution.

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.solidos.neshaniha.FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you put image files in corresponding folder as to fit common tablets resolutions?

Comment: Il upload only an APK file, and upload screenshots in google play.

Comment: I mean did you placed launcher icon in all drawable directories? I.e. `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-ldpi`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have made layout for tablets .
and just replace

### android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"

with

### android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden

"

Answer (score 0):

Check if your targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion have tablets support